# SQL Server 2017 - Support for old SQL Server ODBC Driver (SQLSRV32.dll)?

Tags: drivers, sql-server, sql, odbc

I have a legacy application that currently uses an ODBC connection to an instance of SQL Server 2008. However, we are migrating to a new server running SQL Server 2017. It seems I am not able to create the old SQL Server ODBC driver connection (SQLSRV32.dll) to this new server. I have to use at least ODBC Driver 11 or higher. Problem is my legacy application chokes when using a newer ODBC Driver connection. Wondering if there may be a way to enable connections using old SQL Server ODBC driver (SQLSRV32.dll) for SQL Server 2017. Thanks.